# How to install Java environment (jdk) jdk1.8.0_45 on alpine linux?

Tags: docker, java

When I look at package lists they suggest that all sorts of Java 1 packages exist for Alpine, but when I try to install them I always get

```
apk add openjdk1=1.8.0_45-b14 
apk add openjdk1=1.8.0_45-b14 
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: 'openjdk1=1.8.0_45-b14' is not a valid world dependency, format is name(@tag)([<>~=]version)
```